# How do I merge a list and a csr matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a list of numbers and its `len(lex) = 6064` that looks like this

```
[0,
 0,
 1,
 0,
 0,
 -1,
 1,
 1,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 1,
 0,]
```

and a csr matrix

```
tweets.shape = (6064, 2500)
```

How do I merge them I tried converting them to two lists both, but when I try to work on it I get an error

```
tweets = list(tweets)
lex = list(lex)
tweets_final = np.column_stack([tweets, lex])
```

after I split the data for training I get the following error for

```
nb.fit(X_train, y_train)


ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

how can I add that list as a column of that matrix

Comment: Please read [ask] and give a [mcve].  As of right now I can't even begin to tell what you're asking for.

Comment: Why would you do : `list(tweets)`?

Comment: try converting the list to an array using `np.asarray(mylist)` and then proceed.

Comment: I get the following for tweets_final.shape = (1, 6065)

Comment: it should be (6064,1), or (6064,2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`scipy.sparse.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html) to stack those two horizontally (column wise). We just need to convert the list to a column vector (speaking in terms of sparse matrices) or a 2D array with a single column -

```
scipy.sparse.hstack(( tweets, csr_matrix(lex).T ))

scipy.sparse.hstack(( tweets, np.asarray(lex)[:,None] ))
```

Sample run -

```
In [189]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

In [194]: import scipy as sp

In [190]: a = np.random.randint(0,4,(5,10))

In [192]: a
Out[192]: 
array([[2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1]])

In [193]: b = [9,8,7,6,5]  # equivalent to lex

In [191]: A = csr_matrix(a)  # equivalent to tweets

In [195]: sp.sparse.hstack(( A, csr_matrix(b).T ))
Out[195]: 
<5x11 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 42 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [197]: _.toarray() # verify values by converting to dense array
Out[197]: 
array([[2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 9],
       [0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 8],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 7],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 6],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 5]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. perfect